# Escape ≤ and ≥ in both CMD and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, build, escaping, liquibase

I have a build process where a database is generated from a liquibase changelog file (which is a XML file). It generates a SQL script for a SQL Server database and a SQL script for an Oracle database. Now the CMD at the build process has a problem with `≤` and `≥` and also SQL Server has a problem with `≤` and `≥`

For example this is a statement in my liquibase changelog file

```
<update tableName="MAI_THRESHOLD_DEF">
        <column name="MAI_RSLT_NAME" value="PTB Ratio"/>
        <column name="CURRENT_UNIT" value="Ratio (0 ≤ Decimal ≤ 1)"/>
        <where>MAI_RSLT_REF = 'PT' AND MAI_ID = '5023'</where>
</update>
```

In the cmd of my build process it looks like this: `Ratio (0 â‰¤ Decimal â‰¤ 1)`. 
Despite of that in my SQL script which is created through the build process it was generated right:

```
UPDATE [MAI_THRESHOLD_DEF] 
SET [CURRENT_UNIT] = N'Ratio (0 ≤ Decimal ≤ 1)', [MAI_RSLT_NAME] = 'PTB Ratio' 
WHERE MAI_RSLT_REF = 'PT' AND MAI_ID = '5023'
GO
```

But since the build process already builds a database through CMD it was updated to `Ratio (0 â‰¤ Decimal â‰¤ 1)` in my database. Now even if I escape that I still would have to escape it for SQL Server since `≤` and `≥` also have to be escaped in another way for SQL Server or it will be updated to `Ratio (0 = Decimal = 1)` instead of `Ratio (0 ≤ Decimal ≤ 1)`.

Is there any way to escape both CMD and SQL Server already in my liquibase changelog xml file? Sorry if I explained it in a complicated way but I could not figure out how to describe it easier.

Comment: I don't know anything about liquibase but in every language I have ever worked with you don't use that character. You use two characters. <= or >=

Comment: I would like to avoid using these characters too but unfortunately the user I am doing it for wants to use them.

Comment: Those are not valid inequality characters. Either fix the source or replace those characters with ones that actually work.

Comment: These are no inequality characters, they are data the user wants to insert/update as varchar into the database

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Then you would need to use nvarchar in sql server. I have no idea how you handle that in liquibase.

Comment: The issue may be the encoding of the file. SQL Server Management Studio frequently encodes files in something other than UTF-8 or UTF-16. Liquibase is probably treating the file as UTF-8.